# Algum js esta printando um numero estranho na minha página

Tags: jquery, opencart

Algum `Javascript` ou `js` está printando um número estranho bem no incio da página no [site aqui](http://www.brewheadshop.com.br).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei remover 1 java script por vez, mas não achei a causa do mesmo,

Será que é o próprio `jquery` que esta fazendo aparecer este número estranho?

Alguém já passou por isso ou sabe o que é e pode me orientar?

Comment: Eu diria que é no lado do servidor... estás a usar PHP?

Comment: sim php 5.3
mas isso apareceu do nada sem que nenhuma alteração fosse feita

Comment: realmente mujito estranho isto, esta div no html do layout esta logo abaixo da tag body

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7o3a4rj6p2pyy0m/Captura%20de%20tela%202016-08-26%2018.00.41.png?dl=0

Comment: olha no cod fonte onde o número aparece
https://www.dropbox.com/s/27v0bonue9jvxqh/Captura%20de%20tela%202016-08-26%2018.48.15.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema

`opencart` tem na `header` uma função que printa o usuário do analytics
in `\catalog\view\theme\yourtheme\template\common\header.tpl`

encontrei isto aqui

```
<?php echo $google_analytics; ?>
```

eu apenas comentei